# Ubuntu crontab simple echo to file not working

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to set up some cronjobs on Ubuntu for daily tasks. To do so I added for example the line

```
25 11 * * * ~/test_script.sh
```

to the `sudo crontab -e` table. In the `test_script.sh` I am trying a simple echo to a log file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# file: test_script

 echo "Test" >> ~/test.log
```

When I run the script normally a line with "Test" is added to `test.log`. However at 11:25 nothing seems to happen. I already checked if the time is set correctly using `echo $(date)`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use `/home/USERNAME/test_script.sh` instead. When you say "When I normally run the script..." how do you run in exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should paste the full path of script. For example `25 11 * * * /home/xxxx/test_script.sh`

Comment: Ah I see! Is that because it is the sudo crontab list and therefore `~` is not pointing to the logged in user's home directory anymore?

Comment: Actually, cron runs your commands in your home directory. But for excluding the problems with working directory just add the full path of the file.

Comment: Ok, as it works now the working directory seems to have been somewhere else. Thanks for your help!